# How to find all tables in Mysql which contain certain columns

Tags: mysql

Example :: I want to find all tables which contain both of these columns: userid,productid

Comment: Are you asking if you can query all the tables in the database to find out which ones have those columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to find out which tables in a schema have certain columns you can query the information_schema database like this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'userid'
OR column_name = 'productid'
```

That will show all tables that have either column. If you want to know only those tables that have BOTH columns add a subquery (a JOIN would work as well)

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns c
WHERE column_name = 'userid'
AND (
    SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = c.table_name
    AND column_name = 'productid'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name 
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE column_name IN( 'userid','productid')
 GROUP 
    BY table_name HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```